# How to Start camera when button is pressed?

Tags: android, camera

I am working On an android application. In This i have to implement camera functionality. when i click on button it should start and when i captured image it should back to main application with that image .How can i achieve this?Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in `onClick()`

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
File output = new File(dir,captureimage.png");

cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(output));
String path = output.getAbsolutePath();  <---------here you will get file path also
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO);
```